# Show $\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{e\mid(n/d)}\mu(d)f(e))=\sum_{e\mid n}\sum_{d\mid(n/e)}\mu(d)f(e)$

Tags: number-theory, summation

Need verification as to how

$$\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{e\mid(n/d)}\mu(d)f(e))=\sum_{e\mid n}\sum_{d\mid(n/e)}\mu(d)f(e)$$

I am a little unclear as to how this change works, if it could be clarified for me that would be great.

A slower transition from the RHS to the LHS would be perfect

Also is it true for any functions $f$ and $g$ that: $$\sum_{d\mid n}\sum_{e\mid(n/d)}f(e)g(d)=\sum_{e\mid n}\sum_{d\mid(n/e)}f(e)g(d)$$

---

**My understanding**

I know that since the sums are dependent on different variables, so they are commutative.

After a bit of thought, is it the same as the sum that takes the values such that $ed$ divides $n$ in other words is it the same as:

$$\sum_{ed\mid n}\mu(d)f(e)$$

Comment: That's basically it, you just put your last summation in between the two sides and put equals signs on both sides of it. It's a finite sum, so there's not even convergence issues to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line of interpreting both sums, or alternatively possibly as
$$ \sum_{e,d,c\atop edc=n} \mu(d)f(e)$$
is just the right way to see this.